# Cannot open/create SQLite database in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've 2 files DatabaseViewController.h file which has

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface DatabaseViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;
@property(nonatomic) sqlite3 *contactDb;

@end
```

Another DatabaseViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

//Buid the path for database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *db_path = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(db_path, &_contactDb) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDb, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDb);
    } else {

        _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}


}
```

Unfortunately, the statement

```
if(sqlite3_open(db_path, &_contactDb) == SQLITE_OK)
```

never succeeds.

It just routes to

```
 _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
```

What is the problem?

I did add libsqlite3.dylib to the project. I am using Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to `NSDocumentationDirectory` should be `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Never mind - Forgetting that sqlite_open will also create the database file if it doesn't exist, the problem was just the wrong directory reference.

Comment: On point 2, I inferred that the purpose of this code was to create the database and create the table in the database only if the database didn't already exist. Basically, `viewDidLoad` is simply ensuring that the database is ready to be used, not actually trying to open the database for future operations. Dixit is merely creating it if it doesn't exist. If that was indeed the purpose, then I think that `if` statement is right.

Comment: @Rob As written, the code says "if the database file does not exist then open the database file". That is wrong no matter what. There is nothing in the posted code that properly deals with the file not already existing and is most likely the real problem. You can't create a database file by calling sqlite3_open on a non-existent file.

Comment: If you want to create a database, you use `sqlite3_open`. That function creates the database if it doesn't exist, by default. Only if you use `sqlite3_open_v2` and explicitly omit the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` will the attempt opening of a non-existent database not create it for you (or if you try to open a database in a directory that you don't have write permissions, e.g. outside the sandbox). But `sqlite3_open` will create it if you have write permissions to the location you're trying to open the database.

Comment: @Rob My mistake. I was thinking about the `sqlite3_open_v2` method when I made that statement. I forgot that `sqlite_open` will create the file by default. I'll update my answer. Based in this, the problem was just the wrong directory reference. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed. I wish they'd deprecate `sqlite3_open`, as it's constantly a source of confusion (generally the converse problem, where someone is trying to open a database, get the file name wrong or fail to copy from bundle to `Documents`, and have it create a new blank one without issuing an error).